# Linq Zip combined with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a loop which uses [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to map two different instances of objects `A` & `B` into a new instance of a third object, `C`. The object `C` contains all the fields of `A` & `B` combined.

In other words, they could look like this:

```
class A
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public DateTime TimeOfBirth { get; set; }
}

// A & B combined
class C
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I have a loop which uses AutoMapper to first map `A` into `C`. And then map `B` into the result. Like this:

```
List<C> output = new();

foreach (var a in listA)
{
    C result = _mapper.Map<C>(a);

    _mapper.Map<B, C>(listB.Single(b => b.Id == a.ForeinKey), result);

    output.Add(result);
}
```

I would like to do this with Linq. My initial thought was to use the [Zip method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0), but I cannot get it to work with AutoMapper. I would expect that it should look something like the below, but I cannot get it to work (it doesn't compile):

```
var output = _mapper.Map<C>(listA).Zip(_mapper.Map<C>(listB));
```

What am I missing? Is it even possible to do what I am trying - without making an even bigger mess?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do an in-place mapping the second time, you still need to call `Map<B, C>(b, existingC)`. For that you can use the [`Zip` overload taking a selector fucntion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1))-system-func((-0-1-2)))):

```
var output = _mapper.Map<C>(listA)
    .Zip(listB, (c, b) => _mapper.Map<B, C>(b, c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Join in such case:

```cs
var output = listA
    .Join(listB, a => a.ForeinKey, b => b.Id, (a, b) => 
       _mapper.Map<B, C>(_mapper.Map<C>(a))
    )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What if I want to do a left (outer) join? Do I have to use the annoying syntax then?

Comment: For me Method syntax is also annoying when using joins.  I can easily rewrite to query syntax if it is needed.